# Why am I not able to find the equation of this straight line in my way?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, coordinate-systems

[image]

I want to find the equation of the straight line EB.

**My attempt:**

$$D\equiv\left(\frac{2+6}{2}, \frac{1+3}{2}\right)$$

$$\equiv(4,2)$$

Now, the slope of AD,

$$\frac{2-5}{4-3}$$

$$=-3$$

Now, let $k$ is a constant. The slope of AD and EB are the same as they are parallel. Now, the equation of EB,

$$y=-3x+k\tag{1}$$

Now, $B(2,1)$ is a point of the straight line EB. So, inputting $x=2$ & $y=1$ in $(1)$, we get

$$1=-6+k$$

$$k=7$$

Now, inputting the value of $k$ in $(1)$,

$$y=-3x+7\tag{i}$$

This is the equation of EB.

**My book's attempt:**

Slope of BC,

$$\frac{3-1}{6-2}$$

$$=\frac{2}{4}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}$$

Now, let $k$ is a constant. The equation of EB is

$$y=-2x+k\tag{2}$$

Now, $B(2,1)$ is a point of the straight line EB. So, inputting $x=2$ & $y=1$ in $(1)$, we get,

$$1=-4+k$$

$$k=5$$

Inputting the value of $k$ in $(2)$,

$$y=-2x+5\tag{ii}$$

**Comments:**

$(i)$ & $(ii)$ don't match. I think this is because the figure isn't drawn to scale and AD isn't parallel to EB. Am I correct?

Comment: @Peter Thanks, sir! If you post this as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic This does not look like a linear algebra problem. See if [algebra-precalculus] is more appropriate. I also suggest that you use [geometry].

Comment: @soupless Edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AB and AC do not have the same length hence AD is not the height. You are right.